# How to restore a truncated table

Tags: mysql

How do I restore the data of a truncated table?

Comment: If you do not have a backup data you can not restore the truncated one.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is backups or if you have binary logs that contain all the data.otherwise you cannot restore data :(

Comment: where the binary log file restored, I am in new in mysql

Comment: if you have then you can follow instruction given in this link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

> Truncate operations drop and re-create the table, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

You can restore a table from a backup, if it was