# Recover truncated Mysql database tables - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, data-recovery

I mistakenly truncated my database table. I tried using binary log but realized that it was turned off. Is there a way of recovering the data? I am using XAMPP on an iMAC.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of questions similar to this.

If you do not have a backup or binary logs you can't restore it.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html and [How to restore a truncated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289275/how-to-restore-a-truncated-table)